# Stratified Kfold

Tags: pandas, split, scikit-learn, cross-validation

If I am correct **Stratified kfold** is used so that the dependent variable ratio in the splits is similar to the original data.
What I want to understand is why is it necessary or important to retain that ratio.

Is it necessary for fraud detection problems where data is **highly imbalanced**.
If yes, why?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/understanding-stratified-cross-validation

```
Cross-validation article in Encyclopedia of Database Systems says:

Stratification is the process of rearranging the data as to ensure each fold is a
 good representative of the whole. For example in a binary classification problem
 where each class comprises 50% of the data, it is best to arrange the data such
 that in every fold, each class comprises around half the instances.

About the importance of the stratification, Kohavi (A study of cross-validation
 and bootstrap for accuracy estimation and model selection) concludes that:

stratification is generally a better scheme, both in terms of bias and variance,
 when compared to regular cross-validation.
```

All metrics calculate against the `true` labels. If there is a bias in the system, say it predicts more of one label, a fold with more of said label would give artificially large results.

a methodology to take care of that is to ensure the true labels distribution is very similar for each fold. Then the aggregation of results would be more indicative of system performance.

Comment: Hey, Nathan thanks for the ans. I understand that from metrics perspective it is better to have equal representation of both classes so that a biased model won't give higher results. But is it such that suppose my original data has say.. 1% class A and 99% class B labels. Now when I make a model I must feed it with training data having same proportions of target labels as of original data.

Comment: Not sure, but I think Stratification is NOT built for such imbalanced case, rather for roughly balanced datasets